# Aspect ratio creating gaps between sibling elements

Tags: react-native, aspect-ratio

I have a two dimensional array rendering a grid of squares. The grid should be a square and each square should be a square, as in an aspectRatio of 1.

The basic grid looks like this:

```
function Grid() {

    const grid = [
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
    ]

    return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {grid.map((row, i) => {
          return (
            <View key={i} style={styles.row}>
              {row.map((square, j) => {
                return <View style={styles.square}>{square}</View>
              })}
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </View>
    )

}

const getStyles = (dimension: number) => {
  return StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      width: "100%",
    },
    row: {
      flexDirection: "row",
      gap: 4,
      marginBottom: 4,
      width: "100%",
    },
    square: {
      flex: 1,
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      aspectRatio: 1,
    }
  });
};
```

The content of the squares is irrelevant for now, this will render a 5x5 grid of squares.

The gap and margin create the illusion of borders but this way there are no borders on the sides of the page.

The issue is that depending on the size of the grid, 5x5, 6x6, etc, there will be random gaps between rows. It's almost as if the math doesn't check out, like the screen width mixed with the amount of squares/columns/rows and the gap/margin size is making it impossible to render perfect squares.

No gap between columns:

[image]

Gap between columns creates an unwanted small gap between rows:

[image]

Is that possible? Is there a way to figure out the perfect aspect ratio to render squares while extending the full width of the screen? I feel like it should be possible or there should be a way to make the aspect ratio fill up available space.

I don't mind if the squares aren't perfect as long as there are no unwanted gaps between rows or columns and as long as the grid covers the full width of the screen.

Comment: Can you general one file with a minimal reproducible example so that we can simply copy and paste it and run on our side?

Comment: wdym? this is a basic react-native component. you mean make it into basic html?

Comment: Nah, I was just lazy. It would be ideal if you have the source code that I can copy, paste, and run directly without any extra effort. The code you have now is better than before, but when I run it, I do not get the same screen as shown in the question. For instance, there is no background color setting in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

I did not run into your problem of having weird gap, but maybe I understand your requirements wrong. Anyway, here is my attempt at creating grip that stretches to the width of the screen. It basically uses all of your original code with a few styles discarded.

### Demo

[image]

### Try It Yourself

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/generate-grid-vrl2hy?file=/src/App.js)

### Source Code

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

const genGrid = (row, col, defaultVal = '') => {
  return [...Array(parseInt(row, 10))].map(_ =>
    Array(parseInt(col, 10)).fill(defaultVal),
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [rowStr, setRowStr] = React.useState('4');
  const [colStr, setColStr] = React.useState('4');
  const [grid, setGrid] = React.useState(genGrid(4, 4));

  const onButtonPress = () => setGrid(genGrid(rowStr, colStr));

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <Text>Row: </Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          value={rowStr}
          onChangeText={setRowStr}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <Text>Col: </Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          value={colStr}
          onChangeText={setColStr}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onButtonPress}>
          <Text>Generate Grid</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.container}>
        {grid.map((row, i) => {
          return (
            <View key={i} style={styles.row}>
              {row.map((square, j) => {
                return (
                  <View key={j} style={styles.square}>
                    {square}
                  </View>
                );
              })}
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  container: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  inputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  textInput: {
    width: 50,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  button: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 30,
    width: '30%',
    height: 40,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginVertical: 2,
    width: '100%',
    // borderWidth: 2,
    // borderColor: 'blue',
  },
  square: {
    flex: 1,
    marginHorizontal: 2,
    aspectRatio: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    // borderWidth: 2,
    // borderColor: 'red',
  },
});

export default App;
```